# Copy some lines of email to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm trying to copy some of the lines of an email body to Excel.

Example email:

```
hi team,
please find the following servers
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.4.1
end of email
```

I want to search the emails in a folder and find the lines between the strings "please find the following servers" and "end of email", then copy each line in a row.

So far I have code that copies the whole email body into single row.

```
Sub CopyEmail2Excel()
Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim objSearchFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim mai As MailItem

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objSearchFolder = Inbox
i = 0
If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Inbox is Empty", vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
End If
For Each item In Inbox.Items
    If item.Subject Like "Server list" Then
        vBody = item.body
        Dim xlApp As Object ' Excel.Application
        Dim xlWkb As Object ' Excel.Workbook
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        xlApp.Range("A2").Value = vBody
    End If
Next
Set objSearchFolder = Nothing
Set Inbox = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

HI Split your Mail Body with Lines, try this code it will work

```
 MyOutLookBody = Split(myItem.Body, vbCrLf)
     For i = 0 To UBound(MyOutLookBody)
        If MyOutLookBody(i) <> "" Then
           Call WriteTextFile(StrFile, MyOutLookBody(i))
        End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how i can use this code within my code. I've tried but not able to succeed. It would be helpful if you can use the sample mail and re post my code including yours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man for the help with. I did some study to understand the things and was finally able to pull things out.

```
Sub ol2excel()
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim text() As String
Dim xlApp As Object ' Excel.Application
Dim xlWkb As Object ' Excel.Workbook
Dim host() As String

For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
    If oAccount = "#original Account name#" Then
        Set oMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
text() = Split(Replace(oMail.body, "end", "servers"), "servers")
content = text(1)
msgbox content

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Range("A1") = content

    End If
Next

End Sub
```